# How to get user names to show in a Kyocera TASKalfa job log

Tags: print-server

We have a Kyocera TASKalfa 4550ci, which was previously just installed on a Windows server and shared out, rather than done through Windows Print Services.

I had to install a new file server since the old one died.  Note: I just started here not that long ago, so the previous system was set up before me (and that person is no longer here).  :-)  I installed the new server, installed the print service, and added the printer to Print Management.  Machines on the network can now see it in the directory, and when they install it it grabs the drive from the server.  So all seemed well.

Except apparently where there used to be the user's name in the job log on the printer, now it's just blank.  I've set authentication settings everywhere I can find them, but nothing.  Interestingly, about 4 people still show up in the log, but no one else does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was writing this, I was experimenting, and ended up finding the answer.  Since I'd written the whole question up though, I figured I may as well post it in case anyone else was looking.  Turns out there are two print drivers - the standard, and the KX, with additional functionality.  The KX driver seems to be needed to have this information populate.